# Notification when button submit if 1 value is more than another value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm sorry for my English, I have a form, and I want to give a simple notification when `$sisa_tempo_bro` is less then `$nominal_transaksi` and prevent submitting( and give simple notification that its more than `$sisa_tempo_bro` ), but in real time input (like jQuery), anyone could help me with this?

```
<form id="form" method="post">
<div class="modal fade" id="kontak_tempo_item" role="dialog">
    <div class="example-modal">
        <div class="modal modal-primary">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content" >
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">New Pembayaran Tempo</h4>
                  </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="kode_sub_transaksi" id=kode_sub_transaksi class="form-control"  readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $tampil_tempo['kode_transaksi'] ;?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="vendorname" class="form-control"  readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $tampil_tempo['vendorname'] ;?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="no_po" class="form-control"  readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $tampil_tempo['no_po'] ;?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="status_pt" class="form-control"  readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['status_pt'] ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="userid" class="form-control"  readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['userid'] ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="kategori_transaksi" class="form-control"  readonly="readonly" value="BELANJA-TEMPO"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="jenis_transaksi" class="form-control"  readonly="readonly" value="KREDIT"/>
                  <div class="modal-body" >
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6"><label>Kode Transaksi</label>
                          <label>Kode Tempo</label>
                          <?php
                     $select_max_nomor=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT MAX(kode_transaksi) AS terakhir FROM acc_transaksi WHERE kategori_transaksi='BELANJA-TEMPO' AND kode_transaksi LIKE '%KTI-%' AND status_pt='$status_pt'"));
                             $nomor_plus_satu=substr($select_max_nomor[terakhir],11,4)+1;
                             $bulan_tahun=date("mY");

                             if(substr($select_max_nomor[terakhir],4,6)==$bulan_tahun) // GANTI NOMOR PER TAHUN 
                                {
                                    $nomor_urut="KTI-".$bulan_tahun."-".sprintf("%04s",$nomor_plus_satu);
                                }
                            else{
                                    $nomor_urut="KTI-".$bulan_tahun."-0001";
                                }

                          ?>
                          <input type="text" name="kode_transaksi" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $nomor_urut; ?>" readonly="readonly"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Sisa Tempo</label>
                          <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly" style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold" value="
                          <?php 
                                if($sisa_tempo_bro=='0')
                                {
                                    echo 'LUNAS';
                                }
                                elseif($sisa_tempo_bro <>'0')
                                {
                                 echo number_format($sisa_tempo_bro,0,",",".")."";
                                }
                           ?>
                          "/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <label>Akun Asal</label>
                          <select class="form-control" name="akun_asal" id="cmbAkun" required>
                            <option value="">** Pilih Salah Satu **</option>
                            <?php
                                include ("koneksi.php"); 

                                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM acc_nama_akun WHERE jenis_akun='DEBET' ORDER BY nama_akun ASC");

                                while($query = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                                    ?>
                                     <option value="<?php echo $query['kode_nama_akun']; ?>"><?php echo $query['nama_akun']; ?></option>
                                    <?php
                                    }
                                    ?>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Sisa Saldo</label><br />
                            <select class="form-control" id="cmbSaldo" style="width:270px; height:30px; font-weight:bold;color:#F00;">
                            <option value="0" required>** Auto **</option>
                            </select>                         
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Nominal Cicilan Tempo</label><br />
                        <input class="form-control" name="nominal_transaksi" id="nominal_transaksi" type="text" onkeyup="formatangka(this)" style="width:270px;" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Tanggal Pembayaran Tempo</label>
                          <input type="date" name="tgl_transaksi" class="form-control" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputFile">Upload File Scan</label>
                            <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" required>
                            <p style="color:#FFF">Format file harus .jpg / .jpeg / .png / .gif </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-item"><b>Keterangan</b><br />
                          <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="descr" placeholder="Enter ..." style="max-height:150px; max-width:100%"></textarea>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">CLOSE</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="finish" class="btn btn-outline">SAVE</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all where this `$sisa_tempo_bro` came from? Well if you stored already both variables `$sisa_tempo_bro` AND `$nominal_transaksi`, then call it inside script like so :

```
<script>
$(function () {
  var ssa_tempo = '<?php echo $sisa_tempo_bro;?>';
  var nml_trans = '<?php echo $nominal_transaksi;?>';

  // do checking here
  if  ( ssa_tempo < nml_trans ) {
    // notified something here
    alert('less');
    // disabled submit button
    $(':submit').prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
</script>
```

**Updated**

If `ssa_tempo` value received the float type like `500.10`, then you need to parse it into string then replace it. See below :

```
// suppose ssa_tempo value is 500.10
// parse it using toString() as float doesn't have
// method replace
// then escape the `.` with `\`
var rep_sisa_tempo = ssa_tempo.toString().replace(/\./,"")
// output should be 5001
```

Comment: thank you, it work but it only change the first (.) it find, not all (.) in the text field i inputed
example the value 500.000.000
it only show 500000.000
but it should be 500000000
any advice ?

Comment: Use this `replace(/\./g,'');`, for global search

Answer (score 0):

thank for the code, it work like charm, but i came up with another case after modified your code like this

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function formatangka(objek) {
   a = objek.value;
   b = a.replace(/[^\d]/g,"");
   c = "";
   panjang = b.length;
   j = 0;
  var ssa_tempo = '<?php echo $sisa_tempo_bro;?>';
  var nml_trans = '<?php echo $nominal_transaksi;?>';
  var rep_sisa_tempo = ssa_tempo.replace(/./,"")
  var rep_nml_trans = nml_trans.replace(/./,"")

   for (i = panjang; i > 0; i--) {
     j = j + 1;
     if (((j % 3) == 1) && (j != 1)) 
     {
       c = b.substr(i-1,1) + "." + c;
         if  ( rep_sisa_tempo < rep_nml_trans ) {
        // notified something here
        alert('less');
        // disabled submit button
        $(':submit').prop('disabled', true);
       }
      else {
                alert('less').close();
          }
     } 
     else {
       c = b.substr(i-1,1) + c;
     }
   }
   objek.value = c;
}
</script>
```

how to replace and dot value to space, example :
var `ssa_tempo` = 400.000 ( a dot value in the middle)
var `nml_trans` = 500.000 ( a dot value in the middle)
when i input 500 in the `textfield` the notification came up, how to overcame that?

Comment: sorry for my bad english, im too excited :)

Comment: you should update the question inside your post. Not as answer. Remove this and update there. Anyway, you want to remove `.` ?

Comment: not to remove, but to replace {.} to {(blank)} it, so your code can work.